# Iterate through Array and extract data

Tags: php, arrays, facebook-graph-api, multidimensional-array

I am trying to iterate through this array http://2of1.com/zee/ZEES%20SMS%20SERVICE.html and extract the data.

I was using:

```
foreach ($graphObject['data'] as $key => $value){
                    $string = $value->message;
                    $link = $value->actions[0]->link;
                    $pic = $value->picture;
                    $post_id = $value->id;
}
```

But it is no longer working after i added a second source to the array.

When i try:

```
foreach ($graphObject as $key => $value){
                        $string = $value->data[0]->message;
                        $link = $value->data[0]->actions[0]->link;
                        $pic = $value->data[0]->picture;
                        $post_id = $value->data[0]->id;
```

I get only the first entry values from data[0] and it does not iterate through all the data. What i need is the data from  data[0] data[1] data[2] data[3]... etc etc... Please help. Thank you!

Comment: The output of `var_export()` is easier to fiddle with than that of `print_r()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably something like

```
foreach ($graphObject as $keyEntry => $entry){
    foreach( $entry->data as $data ) {
        echo $data->picture, "<br />\r\n";
        foreach( $data->actions as $action ) {
            echo $action->link, "<br />\r\n";
```